# How can I programatically get keyboard focus on a WPF TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, treeviewitem

I'm trying to programatically set keyboard focus to a tree view item (under certain conditions).  I've tried 2 methods of setting focus, both of which successfully obtain focus on the `TreeViewItem`, but lose keyboard focus.

The tree view is bound to a view model:

```
<TreeView Name="solutionsModel" TreeViewItem.Selected="solutionsModel_Selected"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

I'm trying to set focus via the `TreeViewItem` `Selected` routed event:

```
private void solutionsModel_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (solutionsModel.SelectedItem != null && solutionsModel.SelectedItem is SolutionViewModel)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource != null && e.OriginalSource is TreeViewItem)
        {
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(solutionsModel, e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set focus on the `TreeViewItem` in the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <!--
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        -->
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Both of these methods get focus, but lose keyboard focus (`TreeViewItem.IsSelectionActive` is false).  No other element in the window has focus or keyboard focus that I can tell (in a test, I only have one read only textbox on another panel that could get focus).  Interestingly, I can get keyboard focus on the (commented out) `MultiTrigger` where `IsSelectionActive` is false, but of course that forces keyboard focus on the `TreeViewItem` at all times.

Is there another way to have a better chance of getting keyboard focus, and what are some conditions where keyboard focus cannot be obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better ways, but I found a way to do this by extending `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem`, to have a separate `NeedsFocus` property to trigger when to set focus.

The tree view:

```
    <local:ModelTreeView x:Name="solutionsModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    </local:ModelTreeView>
```

The updated (partial) control template:

```
<Style d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type local:ModelTreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="NeedsFocus" Value="{Binding NeedsFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ModelTreeViewItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="NeedsFocus" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></Setter>
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The extended classes:

```
public class ModelTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new ModelTreeViewItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is ModelTreeViewItem;
    }
}

public class ModelTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
{
    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>This property gets or sets whether the item needs focus.</summary>
    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NeedsFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NeedsFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(ModelTreeViewItem));
    public bool NeedsFocus
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(NeedsFocusProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(NeedsFocusProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new ModelTreeViewItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is ModelTreeViewItem;
    }
}
```

In the view model, `NeedsFocus` is set to false whenever `IsSelected` is set.

Answer (score 3):

I'd add this as a comment if I could but, why not just have the `TreeView` handle the focus and work with the item abstractly using the `TreeView.SelectedItem`.  The tree view would always be able to know which item was selected when the typing started.  If an item was selected then the `TreeView` is in focus and you can pipe the keyboard commands through to the item.

Comment: Thanks Joshua.  In my case I'm trying to minimize code behind and let the user be able to execute commands on the tree view item context menus using input gestures (without having to reselect the node).  At the moment, I'm extending TreeViewItem to add a NeedsFocus property that I can use for the MultiTrigger.